# How to generate 4 WEP keys with linux commands?

Tags: command-line, security, hashsum

I have a sagem router. this router is able to generate 4 WEP keys from a given passphrase.

Example:

> Passphrase: "hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha"
>
> key1: **b583bc6804d5c1d7fc2ae46972**
>
> key2: d0494a8087e8d742e9e93cf2f5
>
> key3: f0c5af9a3ab7e54337767db1a9
>
> key4: 7e95d22229dacb8f09c9bbd1d7

I m wondering how it can generate 4 keys.

I can use md5sum to generate 1 key like this:

> $ echo -n "hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha" | md5sum
>
> **b583bc6804d5c1d7fc2ae46972** 842868

Are there a way to generate the 4 keys and not only one key with linux command?

Comment: First, a WEP key isn't generated using MD5 hashing, it uses RC4.  Second, the reason you can generate multiple is because a WEP key is usually an IV (initialization vector (usually the current time or a random number) and your key: (IV + Key) -> RC4 = WEP key

Comment: also this is a dupe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446910/how-to-generate-4-wep-keys-with-linux-commands)

Comment: Cross post here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292656/how-to-generate-4-wep-keys-with-linux-commands, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446910/how-to-generate-4-wep-keys-with-linux-commands, and here.

Comment: @h3rrmiller. you can generate a WEP key from passphrase using MD5 hashing please see page 23 of this [document](http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~pld/courses/449/fall08/WEP_password_cracker.pdf)

Comment: @h3rrmiller RC4 is used in the WEP encryption and not in the WEP key generation

Comment: @MOHAMED Yes, I know.  As I already stated, your question confused me.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to do it (if you dont care to take an IV + key and send it through RC4) is:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 4 ]
do
    dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=16 2>/dev/null | xxd -ps
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

This will generate four 128-bit wep keys.  Adjust `count` for different strengths

Comment: are there a standard way to generate the 4 WEP keys

Comment: the standard way is `(IV + key) -> RC4 = WEP key`

Comment: could you point me to the standard. looking for link to the standard document

Comment: the answer is wrong. the IV and the RC4 are used in the encryption. An IV is added to the WEP key in the encryption for more security.

Comment: @MOHAMED This answer is not wrong.  That is how WEP works...  Your question is very hard to follow as it is not very clear what you are looking for.  A WEP key is nothing more than a hexadecimal string of variable length.

Comment: Using IV and RCS to generate WEP keys from passphrase  is not true. And I could not confirm that there is a standard way to do . but this [document](http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~pld/courses/449/fall08/WEP_password_cracker.pdf) conatins the way to generate the 64-bit WEP key and it's based on `XOR` mapping and `PRNG` (page 18). and it contains the way to generate the 128-bit WEP key and it's based on MD5 hashing

Comment: The answer is not wrong only if my question was about how the WEP encryption works. But my question was about how to generate WEP keys from a passphrase

Comment: @MOHAMED Clearly there was a miscommunication then.  Like I said your question is very unclear.